# Android onBackPressed handling with new Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I need some suggestions;

I'm experimenting with Navigation library. I have a fragment which has a webView. I want to check if it `canGoBack` and do so if it can, otherwise not interfere.

**1. Interface approach**: Since Navigation is handling transactions, I don't create an instance of my fragment manually anymore, which I can assign as a listener in activity.

**1. Key listening:** I really think it looks ugly and I don't think it's a generic solution, so I skip this one.

I need some opinions on how can it be done with Navigation library. When you try to get `currentDestination` from `navController`, it's `NavigationDestination` object which provides information about current fragment, such as label given in xml.

When I inspect `fragmentManager`, I see that `backStack` is empty & fragment transaction took place without a tag.

IMHO it wouldn't fit the concept of the library to do `findFragment` kind of operations to somewhat interact with current fragment, but I can't seem to find a way through with it at the moment. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 11):

I found a way to do it as before with interface or base fragment class.

in Activity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val f = currentFragment
    if (f !is BaseFragment || f.onBackPressed()) {
        if (!findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}

val currentFragment: Fragment?
    get() = nav_host_fragment.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

in BaseFragment:

```
open fun onBackPressed() = true /*or false if you want to prevent navigation*/
```

Answer (score 5):

We can directly handle OnBackPressed from any fragment

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher
        .addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            //Handle back event from any fragment 
        }
    })
```

Put above code in onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

[OnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback) can be used for this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.addOnBackPressedCallback {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleOnBackPressed")
        //Your custom back behaviour
        return@addOnBackPressedCallback false
    }
}
```

Return `false` if you want the default back behaviour to execute. Return `true` to ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

I used this code to achieve `onBackPressed` in fragment.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (binding.edtText.length() > 0){
                    binding.edtText.text.clear()
                } else {
                    if(!findNavController().navigateUp()) {
                        if (isEnabled) {
                            isEnabled = false
                            requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```